# strlen in c returning a negative result

Tags: c, unix, system

Program snippet :-

```
if((fd = open(buf_serv, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
    char c[MAXLEN+1];
    snprintf(c, sizeof(c), ": can't open, %s\n", strerror(errno));
    n = strlen(c);
```

...

```
gdb :-
102     if((fd = open(buf_serv, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
(gdb) n
104        snprintf(c, sizeof(c), ": can't open, %s\n", strerror(errno));
(gdb) p sizeof(c)
$1 = 4097
(gdb) n
105        n = strlen(c);
(gdb) p strlen(c)
$2 = -1428323296
(gdb) n
...
```

Can anyone please tell me how come strlen is returning a negative number? (which is crashing my program with a sigsegv signal)

Thanks in advance all!

```
(gdb) l
101
102     if((fd = open(buf_serv, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
103        char ch[MAXLEN+1];
104        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "foo", 3);
105        sprintf(ch, ": can't open, %s\n", strerror(errno));
106        n = strlen(ch);
107        write(writefd, ch, 100);
108     } else {
109        while((n = read(fd, buf_serv, MAXLEN)) > 0) {
110             write(writefd, buf_serv, n);
(gdb) p ch
$1 = ": can't open, No such file or directory\n", '\000' <repeats 4056 times>
(gdb) p strlen(ch)
$2 = -1428323296
```

Comment: Could you specify errno type? Also I would highly advice to print sizeof(c) since I always trip on that one.

Comment: `strlen()` *cannot* return a negative value. Its result is of type `size_t`, which is an unsigned type. I don't why `p strlen(ch)` in gdb is showing a negative value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You dont need to use strlen since snprintf returns number of characters printed, if buffer was large enough to fit all characters including terminating `\0`. [Source](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) provided by @Casey in comments (probably).

So make sure to check if returned value is not negative and is less then buffer size. Also check function documentation provided by your compiler, since implementations may vary.

Comment: Thanks mate, this seemed to do the trick.
int ret = snprintf(buf + n, sizeof(buf) -n , ": can't open, %s\n", strerror(errno));write(writefd, buf, n + ret);

Comment: This answer is incorrect. From N1570 §7.21.6.5 "The `snprintf` function" p3: "The `snprintf` function returns the number of characters that **would have been written** had `n` been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative
value if an encoding error occurred. Thus, the null-terminated output has been completely written if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than `n`." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @Casey Yes in deed, my answer is correct only then buffers is large enough to fit all data.

Answer (score 8):

It's just that you can't use GDB :P

```
(gdb) n
105        n = strlen(c);
(gdb) p strlen(c)
```

GDB shows the ***next line to be executed.*** So at the time you are printing `n`, it's yet uninitialized. Write `n <enter>` one more time before printing `n`.

Comment: (gdb) run
...

102     if((fd = open(buf_serv, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {

(gdb) n
104        snprintf(c, sizeof(c), ": can't open, %s\n", 
strerror(errno));

(gdb) p sizeof(c)

$1 = 4097

(gdb) n

105        n = strlen(c);

(gdb) p strlen(c)

$2 = -1428323296

(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000006020a0 in strlen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 ()

Comment: @h2co3, so now hopefully you can see that what I'm talking about is indeed legitimate.

Comment: (gdb) p strlen(c)
$2 = -1428323296

Comment: @user2252999 No, sorry. I can't read that mess. Please consider updating your question and formatting the code.

Answer (score -3):

`strlen()` returns the difference between strings on some compilers.
    so if for example `strlen("a","b")` is there then this will return 1;
    while `strlen("b"...` *Note: original answer truncated*

Comment: Could you name such compiler, since it seems to me that you're talking about strcmp.